# XML file to AVRO conversion using mapreduce(Java)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a task to convert xml file avro format using mapreduce. Could some one please suggest me the approach to complete this task.

If have some sample code it will be very helpful.

Thank in advance.

Thanks,
Rackto

Answer (score 0):

Build a mapreduce with an XmlInputFormat (like this one https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java), an AvroKeyValueOutputFormat and a specific business logic inside your mapper or map/reducer:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(XmlInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(AvroKeyValueOutputFormat.class);
AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));
AvroJob.setOutputValueSchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.INT));
```